# How can I cancel Windows 10 updates which fail on every boot?

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 tries to install updates and reboots a few times and it will fail and rollback a few times. That's annoying and takes an hour. At the end I can log on. When I reboot, same events will repeat.

What can I do to prevent these unsuccessful upgrade attempts? Is there any mechanism like startup folder, autoexec, etc... that Windows checks at boot phase. So I can delete or disable it.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  There is a known problem with certain updates, which report as having failed, but they were actually successful.  What edition of Windows 10 are you using?  Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.  *I went ahead and remove the inappropriate language from your question.*

Comment: share the logs from C:\Windows\logs\cbs so that we can see what fails.

Answer (score 0):

**How to Delete Downloaded Windows Updates Which Failed to Install**

> The Software Distribution folder in Windows operating system is a
>   folder located in the Windows directory and used to temporarily store
>   files which may be required to install Windows Update on your
>   computer. It is thus required by Windows Update and maintained by
>   WUAgent.

**Renaming SoftwareDistribution folder:**

```
net stop wuauserv
net stop bits
rename c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.bak
net start wuauserv
net start bits
```

**Deleting SoftwareDistribution folder:**

```
net stop wuauserv
net stop bits
del c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution /q /s
net start wuauserv
net start bits
```

Conclusion: Deleting the downloaded files fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem before .

**solution:**(this will disable updates BY SETTING METERED CONNECTION)

i changed my connection to metered to stop future update's .

i removed downloaded update files by using disk cleanup so it remove updates to be installed then your system will not force you to update (*this clears currently downloaded update files*) .

P.S : if you want to skip update after downloading <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
then shutdown ..

upgrades fail's if it didn't meet requirements

Comment: I don't want to disable future updates. I want to cancel current update(s).

Comment: @NimeCloud then use diskclean up

Comment: which deletes downloaded update files